# Где было бы правильно расположить логин и пароль от БД в PHP при написании API

Tags: php

Где было бы  правильно  расположить логин и пароль от БД в PHP при написании API?

Я поместил логин и пароль  в :

```
public_html ----|
                |
                |-API --- api.php
```

и боюсь что его от туда как то украдут. Где было бы правильно располагать пароль и логин от БД?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас есть сервер и `php` интерпретатор, в коде не будет ошибок и/или показ нативных ошибок будет выключен (на проде обязательно), то никак.

Я например придерживаюсь такой структуры в своих проектах:

```
/var/www/vhosts/site.ru/
                       - htdocs // веб директория
                           - index.php // один входной файл
                       - protected // не доступная из вне директория с кодом
                       - vendor // библиотеки
```

### UPD

Есть только 2 варианта, которые приходят на ум:

1. Если у кого-то есть доступ к серверу (`ftp`, `ssh` и т.п.)
2. Если сервер плохо настроен и интерпретатор упадет, то возможен показ `php` как текста в браузере.

И еще, закрывайте удаленный доступ к БД. Только локальный доступ, или с разрешенных `IP` адресов. Если вам нужно подключится удаленно, коннектитесь поверх `ssh` тунеля.

Comment: protected - находится на уровне htdocs/oublic_html , это считается недоступная категория? И как отключить показ нативных ошибок? И еще вопрос:  что на проде обязательно - что это значит? и еще вопрос - Если у вас есть сервер и php интерпретатор -  как можно это понять?

Comment: @semiromid `protected` находится на уровень выше веб директории.  Показ ошибок на продакшене надо выключать – http://php.net/manual/ru/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Comment: интерпретатор упадет - это как? DDoS?

Comment: @semiromid да, например `DDos`, что вряд ли, если будут ддосить, то скорее сразу ляжет железо. Или какая то системная ошибка. Или если `php` кто-то удалить из ОС

Comment: Может и на первые вопросы которые расположены в комментарии ответите? а то там не понятно.

Comment: @semiromid так ответил же – [коммент](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/475978/Где-было-бы-правильно-расположить-логин-и-пароль-от-БД-в-php-при-написании-api/475985?noredirect=1#comment540261_475985)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33191/discussion-between-korytoff-and-semiromid).